# wrong header in a book reference part

Tags: bibliographies, books, sv-classes

I am writing a book and have a little problem with the header in the references part:

The header in even pages is the chapter name and in odd pages is the section name.

Now, When I introduce the bibliography after the appendix, the header of even pages is still the name the appendix chapter.

Here is what I use:

```
\documentclass[graybox,envcountchap,sectrefs]{svmono}

% choose options for [] as required from the list
% in the Reference Guide

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

%
\usepackage{type1cm}         

\usepackage{makeidx}         % allows index generation

\usepackage{graphicx}        % standard LaTeX graphics tool
                             % when including figure files

\usepackage{multicol}        % used for the two-column index

\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}% places footnotes at page bottom

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,oldgerm,epsfig,graphics,float,rotating,rotate,enumerate,euscript,cite,subfigure,ifthen,longtable,array}

\usepackage{xcolor,rotating,adjustbox,pdflscape}

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{rotating,pbox}

\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}


% see the list of further useful packages
% in the Reference Guide

\makeindex             % used for the subject index
                       % please use the style svind.ist with
                       % your makeindex program

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\author{name}

\title{book}

%\subtitle{-- Monograph --}

\maketitle

\mainmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%\include{part/part}

\include{chap1/chap1}

\include{chap2/chap2}

\include{chap3/chap3}

\include{chap4/chap4}

\include{chap5/chap5}

\include{chap6/chap6}

\include{appendix/appendix}

\backmatter%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\bibliography{Bib/data-base}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How shall we know what's in your preamble? Please post a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: I editted the question and put more details in it

Comment: This is the SVMONO package that I downloaded from the springer

Comment: The example is still not compilable and so does not show the problem. Please read: [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) BTW: You should not load packages more than once. It makes it harder to manage the file. Without MWEB I could only suggest to add, e.g., `\markboth{}{}` after `\backmatter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your explanations

BTW, I solved the problem by using this:

```
\Extrachap{References}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{Bib/data-base}
```